# SQL Select multiple rows into one displayed row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row

My situation is I have two tables. I want to join them together and have duplicate records appear on the same line. Mock table structures given below

MainTbl
Cols: MKey1,MKey2,MData1,MData2,MData3

SuppTbl
Cols: SPrimaryKey,SKey1,SKey2,SData1,SData2

I want to LEFT JOIN MainTbl to SuppTbl. However, SuppTbl contains duplicates of SKey1 and SKey2 combo key.

The results I want are below, Where "-#" indicates the duplication number.

MKey1,MKey2,MData1,MData2,MData3,SData1-1,SData2-1,SData1-2,SData2-2

In essence, all fields from the join should be contain on one row based one Key1 and Key2.

**ATTEMPTED ANSWER BY SEAN W**

```
SELECT
    MainTbl.MKey1,
     MainTbl.MKey2,
    tcd.SData1 AS SData11,  
    tcd.SData2 AS SData22,
    tcr.SData1 AS SData12,  
    tcr.SData2 AS SData22
FROM MainTbl
LEFT JOIN SuppTbl tcd
ON MainTbl.MKey1=tcd.SKey1 AND MainTbl.MKey2=tcd.SKey2
LEFT JOIN SuppTbl tcr
ON MainTbl.MKey1=tcr.SKey1 AND MainTbl.MKey2=tcr.SKey2
WHERE tcd.SData1 < tcr.SData1
```

*RESULT* No Success. Did not pull any records.

Comment: Does Table2 have a maximum of two matches?

Comment: @tony Not necessarily. It could have one or two. If it has more it's a rare case, but possible. I do have conditions that could limit it to two. "WHERE DataD1 = 4" and "WHERE DataD1=22"

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: at best, you'll wind up with rows with some columns not populated, where there's only 1 join. that fine? Then just do 2 left joins to the second table and return the results.

Comment: @SeanW That won't work. It'll create duplicate column data if any rows at all exist in Table2.

Comment: You columns and and sample data don't match, and your where condition (in comment) will return zero records for the sample data. That combined with 500+ characters without a line break is very difficult to read and will present a barrier to people who want to help you.

Comment: @ConradFrix I have adjusted my post to be more user friendly. Please let me know if that helps you understand what I am attempting.

Comment: @Tony - the last line of sql in my answer below should address the duplicates. Otherwise you need to explain what logic would be used to avoid the duplicate situation.

Comment: @steventnorris - this is a great tool for setting up models of the problems that you are trying to solve in sql - [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer. I've trimmed it down a bit for simplicity's sake, but it works great so long as there are WHERE conditions that can be applied, as there are in my case.

```
SELECT 
    MainTbl.MKey1,
    MainTbl.MKey2,
    tcd.stat AS SData11,
    tcr.stat AS SData12
FROM MainTbl
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT * FROM SuppTbl WHERE SData1 <> 22
) tcd
ON MainTbl.MKey1=tcd.SKey1 AND MainTbl.MKey2=tcd.SKey2
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT * FROM SuppTbl WHERE SData1 = 22
) tcr
ON MainTbl.MKey1=tcr.SKey1 AND MainTbl.MKey2=tcr.SKey2
```

Comment: You really should have provided more information on what SData1 was storing, and how that would affect the selecting of rows.

Comment: where has that `22` suddenly popped up from ?!

Comment: @whytheq The 22 was an answer to a question Tony asked in the comments of the OP.

Comment: @SeanW I gave a depiction of what I was attempting so as to get direction. The direction I was given, and the questions I was asked led me to this answer. The information as to what SData1 was holding was asked and answered in the comments of the OP. If you had asked, I would have gladly given you more information. Thanks for looking things over.

Answer (score 4):

Revised (comments after):

```
CREATE TABLE MainTbl (MKey1 int,MKey2 int,MData1 varchar(10),MData2 varchar(10),MData3 varchar(10))
CREATE TABLE SuppTbl (SPrimaryKey int,SKey1 int,SKey2 int,SData1 varchar(10),SData2 varchar(10))

INSERT INTO MainTbl VALUES (1, 1, '1MData1', '1MData2', '1MData3')
INSERT INTO SuppTbl VALUES (1, 1, 1, '1SData1-1', '1SData2-1')
INSERT INTO SuppTbl VALUES (2, 1, 1, '1SData1-2', '1SData2-2')

INSERT INTO MainTbl VALUES (1, 2, '2MData1', '2MData2', '2MData3')
INSERT INTO SuppTbl VALUES (3, 1, 2, '2SData1-1', '2SData2-1')

SELECT
    MainTbl.MKey1,
    MainTbl.MKey2,
    tcd.SData1 AS SData11,  
    tcd.SData2 AS SData22,
    tcr.SData1 AS SData12,  
    tcr.SData2 AS SData22
FROM MainTbl
INNER JOIN SuppTbl tcd
ON MainTbl.MKey1=tcd.SKey1 AND MainTbl.MKey2=tcd.SKey2
LEFT JOIN SuppTbl tcr
ON MainTbl.MKey1=tcr.SKey1 AND MainTbl.MKey2=tcr.SKey2
AND tcd.SPrimaryKey < tcr.SPrimaryKey
```

Now this won't work 100% for those instances where you have 2 rows in SuppTbl: it will give two result rows - one will be fine and the other you will want to exclude. To exclude it, you have to provide some more information on how to identify those instances where it will have >1 SuppTbl row. You mentioned above in the comments "WHERE Data1 = 4". So that would need to be part of a WHERE clause. It would be something like:

```
 WHERE tcd.SData1 = 4
```

This might then EXCLUDE the single SuppTbl row. So you need to provide information on how to NOT have that row filtered out. Maybe:

```
 WHERE tcd.SData1 IN (4, 22)
```

(This won't work with the data in the tables, above).

Comment: I tried your answer (posted attempt above) but no records were pulled. Maybe is one of the assumption? What information might help you understand my structure better?

Comment: Looked back over your answer, and actually this is where I got a lot of my direction from towards the final solutions. Apologies if I didn't give credit where credit was due.